# Dual results in Query

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere, isql

I have a query where I am getting double the results in my line items. Here is a copy of what I have. Do I have to do the joins differently? Here is also a screen shot of what the results look like. Every line item is doubled up. [image]

```
SELECT 
  ds_id as "TMP", 
  ds_ship_date as "Ship Date", 
  ds_ref1_text as "Container Number", 
  o.co_name as "Origin", 
  o.co_city as "Origin City", 
  o.co_state as "Origin State", 
  de_arrdate as "Deliver Date", 
  de_arrtime as "Arrival Time", 
  de_deptime as "Departure Time", 
  ds_bill_charge as "TMP Total Charges",
  (CASE ds_ship_type WHEN '2201' THEN 'MONTREAL'
    WHEN '2202' THEN 'DRYVAN'
    WHEN '2203' THEN 'BROKERAGE'
    WHEN '2204' THEN 'OLD BROKERAGE'
    WHEN '2205' THEN 'LIFTING'
    WHEN '2206' THEN 'WAREHOUSE'
  END) AS "Division",
  dba.disp_items.di_qty,
  dba.disp_items.RateCodename 
FROM dba.disp_ship 
  JOIN dba.disp_events ON de_shipment_id = ds_id 
  JOIN dba.disp_items ON DBA.disp_items.di_shipment_id = dba.disp_ship.ds_id
  JOIN dba.companies o ON o.co_id = ds_origin_id 
WHERE de_site = ds_findest_id 
  AND TMP = '70189'
ORDER BY ratecodename desc
```

Comment: it would help if you could update the query to include table name prefixes on all column references (at least for the `join/where/group by` clauses); at this point I can't tell if the duplicate rows might be an issue of a missing join clause (ie, the result of a cartesian product); o a more detailed level it may be necessary to review the relationships between these tables and the associated join clauses (eg, how many rows match on for each join clause)

Comment: To me this looks as follows: A `disp_ship` has `disp_events` and `disp_items`. You are selecting both, although they are not directly related (an event doesn't belong to one item, an item doesn't belong to one event). If a ship has two events and two items, you select 2 x 2 = 4 rows for the ship, each event combined with every item. You don't want this, so decide what you want instead. You could `SELECT DISTINCT` to get rid of any duplicates, but you may rather want some aggregation instead, say the total item quantity instead of single quantities or the latest event instead of all events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a GROUP BY. Try like this :

```
SELECT      ds_id AS TMP, ds_ship_date AS ShipDate, ds_ref1_text AS ContainerNumber, o.co_name AS Origin, o.co_city AS OriginCity, o.co_state AS OriginState, de_arrdate AS DeliverDate, de_arrtime AS ArrivalTime, de_deptime AS DepartureTime, 
            ds_bill_charge AS TMPTotalCharges,
            CASE ds_ship_type
                    WHEN '2201' THEN 'MONTREAL'
                    WHEN '2202' THEN 'DRYVAN'
                    WHEN '2203' THEN 'BROKERAGE'
                    WHEN '2204' THEN 'OLD BROKERAGE'
                    WHEN '2205' THEN 'LIFTING'
                    WHEN '2206' THEN 'WAREHOUSE'
            END
            AS Division,
            dba.disp_items.di_qty, dba.disp_items.RateCodename 

FROM        dba.disp_ship
JOIN        dba.disp_events ON de_shipment_id = ds_id
JOIN        dba.disp_items ON DBA.disp_items.di_shipment_id = dba.disp_ship.ds_id
JOIN        dba.companies o ON o.co_id = ds_origin_id
WHERE       de_site = ds_findest_id
AND         TMP = '70189'
GROUP BY    TMP, ShipDate, ContainerNumber, Origin, OriginCity, OriginState, DeliverDate, ArrivalTime, DepartureTime, TMPTotalCharges, Division, di_qty, RateCodename
ORDER BY    ratecodename DESC
```

Comment: It would be more typical to `SELECT DISTINCT` here. But `DISTINCT` is often an indicator for a badly written query. The duplicates exist for a reason (probably a cartesian join of events and items). So it might be better to think this through and decide what is really wanted (a certain event per ship? a certain item per ship? an aggregation, like the total item quantity per ship?) Having said this, I consider this answer a bad advice.